# how to animate multiple images from left to right when web service loading in Android?

Tags: android, xml, web-services, android-animation, progressdialog

In my application i want show the animation of multiple images from left to right when web service is loading. Basically i am  using progress dialogue  for web service loading. please any one suggest me how to do this.
thank you in advance.

my code:

```
private class getCircleDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
ProgressDialog pdialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }
           @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(PassengerDetailsActivity.this, "Loading....", "");
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlcircle, ServiceHandler.GET);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    jsonarr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
                        jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String circleid = jsonobj.getString("CircleID");
                        String circlename = jsonobj.getString("CircleName");

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } 
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pdialog.dismiss();


        }

    }
```

animation code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView[] images;
    int[] drawables;
    ImageView image;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawables = new int[5];
        images = new ImageView[5];
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        for(int i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            if(i%2 == 0){
                drawables[i] = R.drawable.mobile;
            }else{
                drawables[i] = R.drawable.dth;
            }

            images[i] = image;//new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            images[i].setBackgroundResource(drawables[i]);
        }


        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        //----------------------------------------------
        final AnimationSet rootSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        rootSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        // Create and add first child, a motion animation.
        final TranslateAnimation trans1 = new TranslateAnimation(-100, 100, 0,0);
        trans1.setStartOffset(0);
        trans1.setDuration(900);
        //trans1.setFillAfter(false);
        rootSet.addAnimation(trans1);

        // Add a final motion animation to the root set.
        final TranslateAnimation trans2 = new TranslateAnimation(100, 1000, 0,0);
        //trans2.setFillAfter(false);
        trans2.setDuration(1200);
        //trans2.setStartOffset(800);
        rootSet.addAnimation(trans2);

        rootSet.setRepeatCount(Animation.RESTART);
        rootSet.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);

        // Start the animation.
        AnimationListener listener = new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                images[0].clearAnimation();
                images[1].setBackgroundResource(0);
                images[1].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                images[1].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dth);
                images[1].startAnimation(rootSet);




            }


        };




        trans1.setAnimationListener(listener);
        trans2.setAnimationListener(listener);
        images[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mobile);
        images[0].startAnimation(rootSet);


    }

}
```

Comment: i tried but i am getting only two images...how to add 5 images. please any one help me